# How to use realm with AWS serverless lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, realm, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, realm-mobile-platform

So I'm currently using AWS serverless to make a createObject endpoint, which takes the values from the http body and uses the key-values to store an item in DynamoDB. I am doing this via AWS Lambda. We recently started using Realm (Realm.io) and we see that they have a Javascript library for node. Is it possible to invoke a realm function to store the same object, via AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the Node SDK for Realm is only for the **Professional** and **Enterprise** editions of the Realm Object Server (ROS). The ROS can only be deployed on your own Linux instance.

Please see this for more details: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as Clifton Labrum says, the professional and enterprise editions of the Realm Mobile Platform has a node.js SDK to be used on the server to listen for changes in Realms.

At every change in a Realm, you will get an event, which you can then process as you like. For instance, you can store objects in DynamoDB. You can also just leave the objects in Realms.